# Detecting when a value changes when looping an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an array where there are repeated values.  I need to group like elements, and when the value changes create a new "section".

My array is something like

```
{section: "An Hour before Dinner", title: "Cook peas"},
{section: "An Hour before Dinner", title: "Take pie out"},
{section: "As guests arrive", title: "Mix drinks"},
{section: "Just Before Dessert", title: "Reheat at 325 about 20 minutes."},
{section: "Just Before Dessert", title: "Cut and serve."},
```

I will need to do something like

```
An Hour Before Dinner
  Cook peas
  Take pie out
As guests arrive
  Mix Drinks
Just before dessert
  Reheat at 325 about 20 minutes.
  Cut and serve.
```

Due to the fact that sometimes my array might have fewer or more elements, I need to loop it, and when the value changes create a new heading with the new value and then loop through the elements until the next different item comes up and create the next heading etc.

Comment: Sounds like you could make use of backbone.js

Comment: @Steve: Your array was syntactically incorrect (check the [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7321758/revisions) to see what I changed). I assumed this was a typo when creating the question, rather than a typo present in your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var arr = [
    {section:"An Hour before Dinner", title:"Cook peas"},
    {section:"An Hour before Dinner", title:"Take pie out"},
    {section:"As guests arrive", title:"Mix drinks"},
    {section:"Just Before Dessert", title:"Reheat at 325 about 20 minutes."},
    {section:"Just Before Dessert", title:"Cut and serve."}
];
var s = null;

var html = "";
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i<l; i++) {
    var r = arr[i];
    if (r.section != s) {
        // New section
        s = r.section;
        html += "<h1>"+s+"</h1>"
    } else {
        // Continue old section
    }
    html += "<p>"+r.title+"</p>";
}

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = html;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var events = [/* as in the question */];
var groupedEvents = {};

for (var i = 0; i < events.length; ++i) {
    var time = events[i].section;
    var action = events[i].title;

    if (!groupedEvents.hasOwnProperty(time)) {
         groupedEvents[time] = [];
    }
    groupedEvents[time].push(action);
}
```

Now `groupedEvents` contains:

```
{
     "An Hour before Dinner": ["Cook peas", "Take pie out"],
     "As guests arrive": ["Mix Drinks"],
     "Just before dessert": ["Reheat at 325 about 20 minutes.", "Cut and serve."]
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Actually,my array was like that since it is actually an array of objects, from a Titanium javascript file.  You are correct, of course, with a normal array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are correctly sorted, and in an array "arr" :

```
var pre = '';
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (arr[i].section != pre) displayHeading(arr[i]);
   pre = arr[i];
   displayContent(arr[i]);
}
```